# Every subring of a finite ring is finite, what about the converse?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Every subring of a finite ring is finite, what about the converse?

That is, Let $R$ be a ring, and every proper subring is finite, that is if $R'\subsetneq R$ is a subring of $R$, then $R'$ is finite. Can we show $R$ is finite?

Argue by contradiction. Can we find a infinite ring, whose proper subring is finite?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Not necesarily $1$ in a subring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest example: take the Prüfer group $C(p^\infty)$ ($p$ is any prime), write it additively (the operation is $+$, the neutral element is $0$) then define the product as $xy=0$. You get a ring with zero product. Its (proper) subfrings are exactly the proper subgroups of $C(p^\infty)$. Since all proper subgroups of the Prüfer group are finite, all proper subrings of this ring are finite. More examples are [here](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319532).

Comment: Why proper subring is finite? Any hints?

Comment: Because proper subrings $=$ proper subgroups of $C(p^\infty)$ and those are finite (Google "Prüfer group").

Comment: @xldd Or search on "$p$-quasicyclic group". The multiplicative group of all complex $p$'th roots of unity is one concrete model of $\,C(p^\infty).\,$ For more see e.g. the books: Fuchs, *Abelian groups* or Kaplansky, *Infinite Abelian Groups*.